CRMActAdd Never Expire?
I'm working with the jXchange/Synapsys CRM Enterprise SOAP API and using CRMActAdd call to create a NOTE activity.
Is it possible, with the API, to set a note to never expire? Within Xperience/Synapsys CRM, staff members can manually check off a box within options "Never Expire" and I'm not seeing that as an ability in the API. Might I be missing anything or is this not a possibility?
Thank you.
I have tried a CRMActInq call on an existing NOTE with the "Never Expire" option checked. It returns the ActExpDt as "0001-01-01" however, setting this field to the same in a CRMActAdd call does not set the note activity to never expire.
